# elastic apm for elixir and use of opentelemtry

Tags: elasticsearch, elixir, phoenix-framework, telemetry, elastic-apm

We want to track our elixir phoenix app  using elastic apm. But I could not find an apm agent from elastic.

Someone suggested to use `opentelemetry` along with exporter but I am unable to understand how to use that from the docs. I want to track details like the new relic does like errors and all things.

Previously we used new relic for which there is an open source apm agent but now we want to switch to elastic.I am unable to understand how to use span in the app and how to handle multiple span and where to put them. If anyone can help with that or provide alternate solution to use elastic apm it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true, there isn't an Elixir agent for Elastic APM - you can upvote [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/apm/issues/60) to get the topic more attention.

As you discovered, you can use the OpenTelemetry in the meantime.  To do that, run the OpenTelemetry contrib collector (otel collector) and configure it to export to `elastic` - there is a full explanation [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/open-telemetry-elastic-get-started.html#open-telemetry-elastic-configure) along with this sample configuration:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    endpoint: localhost:55680
processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 1s
    send_batch_size: 1024
exporters:
  elastic:
    apm_server_url: "https://elasticapm.example.com"
    secret_token: "ESS_TOKEN"
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [elastic]
```

In your application, configure the tracer use the [opentelemetry exporter](https://github.com/opentelemetry-beam/opentelemetry_exporter#using).

At that point you'll have a tracer in your application sending traces to the otel collector.  From there, traces will be exported to the Elastic Stack via APM Server.  In summary: `your app -> otel collector -> apm-server -> elasticsearch`

The [Erlang/Elixir Agent Docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-erlang-api#registering-and-using-tracers-directly) have sample code for starting and decorating spans.

Comment: can you tell how to run the otel collector. I cloned the repo did the make command and created the yaml file mentioned on doc link given by you. But they did not show how to run cause it still is not working.

Comment: I did  following: 
added 
`{:opentelemetry_api, "~> 0.3.0"},
 {:opentelemetry_exporter, "~> 0.3.0"}`
 in mix and ran deps.get.
cloned the opentelemetry-collector-contrib and ran the make otelcontribcol  and created yaml file with our configuration as mentioned on doc .
configured the tracer in application.exs acc to [link](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-erlang-api#registering-and-using-tracers-directly) and exporter in config file acc to  [link](https://github.com/opentelemetry-beam/opentelemetry_exporter#using).Then created a span.
can you tell what I am missing out ?